# Access to string resources from databasehelper

Tags: android, string, sqlite

I need to put some default data to database. I made method in my databasehelper:

```
private void putDefaultList(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String nazwaa = null;
    String mark = "0";

    ArrayList<String> nazwa = new ArrayList<>();
    nazwa.add("jjjjjj");
    nazwa.add("kokoko");

    for (int i =0; i<nazwa.size(); i++) {

        nazwaa = nazwa.get(i);
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TodoTable.TABLE_NAME + " (" + TodoTable.COL_2 + ", " + TodoTable.COL_3 + ") VALUES (" + "'" + nazwaa + "'" + ", " + "'" + mark + "'" + ")");
    }
```

This method works but i need to have different languages so the simplest way is to get access to strings.xml but I don't know how in this situation.

I tried 
Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.jjjjjj));
but this crash my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;

    public DbHelper(Context context, String name, int version) {
        super(context, name, null, version);

        // Application Context
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String res = this.context.getString(String_resId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class App like:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Then, in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <application android:name="App" 
        <!-- More properties-->
  >
  </application>
```

Now, in your database helper you can obtain the context this way:

```
Context context = App.getContext();
```

And the desired String:

```
String myString = context.getResources().getString(R.string.jjjjjj);
```

Hope it helps!